# Lightweight edition of Windows 7 or another alike OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, ssd

I have a 64GB SSD, which I use for OS. Windows 7 and 8 use a lot of space once they install all the latest updates. It eats about half of my SSD space. I would like to have a very lightweight edition of Windows 7, because Windows 8 does not have all the drivers my computer needs. I was wondering if there is a way to have the latest updates, Windows 7-8 security, drivers support, great performance and a very lightweight OS. I would use Linux, which would be a great idea in this case, but I need to run software that only works on Windows. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Create it yourself: [RT 7 Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/).

Comment: I was thinking that. Be careful tho, taking out too much breaks things, naturally

Comment: Yes, it's a good tool, but the updates still take more than twice the space the original installation takes.

Comment: I think you can delete de Updates uninstallers, you will only lose the ability to uninstall the Updates, not the Updates themselves

Comment: Yes, I did that before. It saves a little bit of space.

Comment: I might be the only one who remembers good ol' TinyXP :)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft offers a [Windows Embedded Version of Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/windows-embedded-standard-7.aspx) which you can customize the way you need it. Here you can install which functions you want and which not.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Puppy Linux:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppy_Linux
http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm

The aim of this distribution is a lightweight and small linux. Maybe you can find alternative linux based programs nevertheless (there are a lot!).

Alternatively you can install Windows 7 and use an external Hard Drive for your datas.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Unfortunately, it is complicated to find alternatives for the software I use and I am very used to my old programs. The second solution is a good idea, but my point to reduce the size of OS drive is to have heavyweight software and a game or two on the same drive (since SSD increases the speed).

Comment: Have you looked into using Wine? It's a wrapper for Windows applications that runs in linux. So far I've only found a few programs that haven't run properly, and they were video games. Most programs should work fine. http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: If you do try the linux option (and you can try a live version to see if it works first) you could get away with a full blown distro not just puppy linux. Ubuntu only takes something like 10Gb.